# Videos sometimes look striped in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, graphics-card, intel-graphics

My laptop has `i5-7200U` cpu and `AMD Radeon R7 M440` gpu. Sometimes when I try to play videos in Chrome, it looks like this:

[image: video error]

I do not have this issue in firefox.

I checked the codec on the youtube video (it is the same on both browsers):

```
vp09.00.51.08.01.01.01.01.00 (247) / opus (251)
```

What could cause this error? How is it possible to solve it?

Comment: A corrupt cache could be the problem. The video is not downloaded correctly. Try clearing everything in your browser and then try again.

Comment: @LPChip I experience it with videos I've never seen before as well.

Comment: That doesn't matter. A problem in cache can do weird things. For example, it can be that the codec itself in the cache is corrupted. Clearing the cache and app data etc can fix the issue. Given this happens to one browser and not the other, something in the browser is borked, so this is definitely the first step to do to rule out any inconsistencies.

Comment: @LPChip I still have this issue after clearing cache and restarting my laptop

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you, it happens often on Facebook and youtube for certain videos and sure I never watched that video, not even clearing the cache can fix it. This is a very confusing and extremely annoying error.
I **solved that by disabling the "Use Hardware Acceleration when available" in Settings/Advanced**. That worked for me, hope it works for you too.